# Time format on Python tests

Tags: python, django, selenium

I would like to test if the format is something like '03:10 ~ 04:10' in python tests, however I have a problem getting it correctly.
This is my code

```
def test_activity_today_time_format(self):  
    """Test time format is HH:MM    """     
    driver = self.driver    
    # Get page by URL   
    driver.get(self.base_url + "/userk/inbox/")     
    # Check time format     
    self.assertEqual("%H:%M ~ %H:%M",  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[3]").text)
```

I think i got a problem with this logic

```
"%H:%M ~ %H:%M"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are literally comparing the string that is supposed to be time format with the date itself; can't do that. You can use regular expressions. Something like this:

```
text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[3]").text
pattern = re.compile(r"((1?\d)|2[0-4]):[1-5]?\d ~ ((1?\d)|2[0-4]):[1-5]?\d")
self.assertRegexpMatches(text, pattern, "Date format not correct")
```

Comment: Thank you so much... I guess this is what I've been looking for

Comment: I am really new to test... I got this error message... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing/actuser_layouts.py", line 35, in test_activity_today_time_format
    pattern = re.compile(r"((1?\d)|2[0-4]):[1-5]?\d ~ ((1?\d)|2[0-4]):[1-5]?\d")
NameError: global name 're' is not defined

Comment: You need to `import re`.